# Prove that if $6\mid m$ and $3^a\mid\mid m,$ then $3^{a-1}\mid\mid \sum_{k=1}^{m}k^m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $6\mid m$ and $3^a\mid\mid m,$ then $3^{a-1}\mid\mid \sum_{k=1}^{m}k^m.$

($3^a\mid\mid m$ means $3^a\mid m$ but $3^{a+1}\not \mid m.$)

@Ivan Loh 's answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548890/m-in-2-6-42-1806-a-problem-of-sum-of-mth-powers-modulo-m) problem proved this for the case $a=1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m=3^at$, where $3 \nmid t$. Note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}{k^m}=\sum_{j=0}^{t-1}{\sum_{k=1}^{3^a}{(k+j*3^a)^m}} \equiv t\sum_{k=1}^{3^a}{k^m} \pmod{3^a}$$

Note that if $3 \mid k$, then $3^m \mid k^m$ and $m>a$ so $3^a \mid k^m$.

Note that $\phi(3^a) \mid m$.

Thus

$$\sum_{k=1}^{3^a}{k^m} \equiv \sum_{1 \leq k \leq 3^a-1 \, \text{and} \, 3 \nmid k}{k^m} \equiv \sum_{1 \leq k \leq 3^a-1 \, \text{and} \, 3 \nmid k}{1} \equiv \phi(3^a) \equiv 2*3^{a-1} \pmod{3^a}$$

Thus $\sum_{k=1}^{m}{k^m} \equiv 2t*3^{a-1} \pmod{3^a}$ so indeed $3^{a-1} \|\sum_{k=1}^{m}{k^m}$.