# On variants of the Erdős–Moser equation as a reference request, and a computational problem as companion question

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, semiprimes

I'm curious to know if it is known some variants of the Erdős–Moser equation for different sequences of integers $a_m$ strictly increasing $1\leq a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_m<\ldots$

$$a_1^k+a_2^k+\ldots +a_m^k=a_{m+1}^k\tag{1}$$
being $k\geq 1$ an integer. I add here the Wikipedia [*Erdős–Moser equation.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Moser_equation)

> **Question 1.** I would like to know if this problem $(1)$ is in the literature. If you know it from the litearature answer this as a reference request, and I try to search an read the statement of problems similar than $(1)$ for different incraasing sequences of integers $(a_k)_{k\geq 1}$ from the literature. **Many thanks.**

Other question is the following specialization of these variants of Erdős–Moser equation.

> **Question 2.** Here again $m\geq 1$ and $k\geq 1$ are integers, does have any solution $(k,m)$ the equation
> $$s_1^k+s_2^k+\ldots +s_m^k=s_{m+1}^k\tag{2}$$
> where $s_k$ denotes the sequence of semiprimes? **Many thanks.**

Here semiprime means a positive integer $s\geq 1$ that is that is the product of two prime numbers. See the Wikipedia [*Semiprime.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime)

Comment: As aside comment, I think that the case $k=1$ could lead to some known problem in additive number theory.

Comment: You might be interested in my question [Solving $x^k+(x+1)^k+(x+2)^k+\cdots+(x+k-1)^k=(x+k)^k$ for $k\in\mathbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479740/solving-xkx1kx2k-cdotsxk-1k-xkk-for-k-in-mathbb-n) and [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141969/solving-xkx1kx2k-cdotsxk-1k-xkk-for-k-in-mathbb-n) and comments below the questions.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in [the wikipedia about Lander, Parkin, and Selfridge conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lander,_Parkin,_and_Selfridge_conjecture) where you can see $90^8 + 223^8 + 478^8 + 524^8 + 748^8 + 1088^8 + 1190^8 + 1324^8 = 1409^8$.

Comment: Many thanks for these references, I didn't know your conjecture/post @mathlove I just did an experiment for the case of prime numbers $a_k=p_k$ and I found a solution, and for the **Question 2** that is for semiprimes. In some way my question about semiprimes seems to me an exaggeration.