# Why is the following for $B= A^x -(A-1)^x-(A-2)^x-(A-3)^x...(A-n)^x$ as long as $B ≥ 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, exponentiation, perfect-powers

As a web developer that programs in PHP, on my free time I like to run some math algorithms to see the wonder of math.

In this experiment, I wanted to check the final results for $B= A^x -(A-1)^x-(A-2)^x-(A-3)^x...(A-n)^x$ as long as $B  ≥  0$

I will list my "findings" in the following before addressing my question:

**When $x=2$: and starting with $A=2$**

$4 - 1 = 3$

$9 - 4 - 1 = 4$

$16 - 9 - 4 - 1  = 2$

$25 - 16 - 9 = 0$

$36 - 25 = 11$

$49 - 36 = 13$

$64 - 49 = 15$

...

- Notice: when $A = 5$ meaning $25 - 16 - 9 = 0$ we get $B=0$
- Notice: according to my script and fist $1000$ results, starting $36−25=11$ (number $5$ on the list), $B$ always goes up and there are no more than one deductions before $B≥0$

**When $x=3$: and starting with $A=2$**

$8 - 1 = 7$

$27 - 8 - 1 = 18$

$64 - 27 - 8 - 1 = 28$

$125 - 64 - 27 - 8 - 1 = 25$

$216 - 125 - 64 - 27 = 0$

$343 - 216 - 125 = 2$

$512 - 343 = 169$

$729 - 512  = 217$

$1000 - 729 = 271$

...

- Notice: when $A = 6$ meaning $216 - 125 - 64 - 27 = 0$ we get $B=0$
- Notice: according to my script and fist $1000$ results, starting with $512 - 343 = 169$  (as  a peak number $7$ on the list), $B$ always goes up and there are no more than one deduction before $B≥0$

**When $x=4$: and starting with $A=2$**

$16 - 1 = 15 $

$81 - 16 - 1 = 64$

$256 - 81  - 16  - 1 = 158 $

$625 - 256 - 81 - 16  - 1 = 271 $

$1296 - 625 -  256  - 81  - 16  - 1 = 317$

$2401 - 1296 - 625 -  256 - 81 - 16 - 1 = 126$

$4096 - 2401 - 1296 = 399$

$6561 - 4096 - 2401 = 64$

$10000 - 6561 = 3439$

$14641 - 10000 = 4641$

$20736 - 14641 = 6095$

...

- Notice: according to my script and fist $1000$ results, starting with $10000 - 6561 = 3439$  (as  a peak number $9$ on the list), $B$ always goes up and there are no more than one deduction before $B≥0$.

**And it continues like this when $x>3$ ,,,**

I understand that the proportion between consecutive numbers is decreasing as the numbers are growing, but it seems as every list begins with a small bump where $B$ and the amount of deductions is increasing for a bit, then decreasing, and then $B$ is increasing from there on consecutively while the amount of deductions is no more than one.

It seems as if the bumps last longer as $x$  grows bigger.

A) Is there any explanation for the bump and will it occur and grow for all $x$ as $x$ gets bigger?

B) Is $25 - 16 - 9 = 0$ and $216 - 125 - 64 - 27 = 0$ the only examples where $B=0$?

As a self learner I really don't know what I am searching for, so if this is a duplicate please close and refer.

Comment: There's a very clear reason for the "bump". Notice the number of terms you are adding and subtracting on each line. The "bump" occurs any time the number of terms drops. Once it reaches $2$, which it will eventually reach, it'll increase in perpetuity since $x^n-(x-1)^n$ is an increasing function of $x$.

Comment: I asked the question B [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479740/solving-xkx1kx2k-cdotsxk-1k-xkk-for-k-in-mathbb-n), but it hasn't received any complete answer, so I think that the question B is open.